# Facebook Like Button with hash

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

when i try to add to my website a FB Like Button with url+hash ([example.com/#TEST](http://example.com/#TEST))
and i try to click the like button - it shares the link without the hash in the news feed   (example.com).

when i try to setup the button with "%23" instand of "#" ([example.com/%23TEST](http://example.com/#TEST)) - it counts each hash separately in the count box.

is there any way to put a like button with hash - and still count the url without the hash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are creating Facebook like buttons, Facebook uses **cURL** (correct me people) to acces your URL that has metadata. So **if cURL sees different metadata**, per URL, you will get different LIKE buttons.

But this doesn't happen; as on the server side, Facebook sees the same URL for every dynamic `#` enabled link. Since the part of the link before `#` is same. JavaScript (or any Behavior that can create a hash in URL) is ignored, obviously, since its *Behaviour* is a client only thing.

The best possible way would be to create the Button dynamically using JavaScript and change the URL-to-like of each button to something friendly without hash.

```
abc.com/def#part1
abc.com/def#part2

// to
abc.com/def/part1
abc.com/def/part2
```

Only for the curl script to see it as a different URL.

And when the user hits that link - `abc.com/def/part1` - you would be needing **server side help** as well to redirect to the view `part1` from the route `def`. So you would, in your router code, load only upto the route `def` (imagine MVC) and then ask the controller to load the view `part1`, with JavaScript enabled to append the URL hash `#part1`.

Answer (score 1):

These hash tags are for client side actions not server side. You will not be able to use them in your Like Button.

Comment: yup, for that very reason check the 2nd para of my answer which starts with "But". Also, the answer itself is about creating links w/o hash tags to be liked, and then redirecting them